# how to give a instance name?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, instance, scheduler, this

I'm using a third party scheduler in my project
Here is the example, http://scheduler-net.com/docs/simple_.net_application_with_scheduler.html

```
        public ActionResult Index() 
        {
            var scheduler = new DHXScheduler(this);
            scheduler.LoadData = true;
            scheduler.EnableDataprocessor = true;
            return View(scheduler);
        }
```

How can I replace the word "this" with a instance name ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you define a constructor this way:

```
public MyConstructor()
{
   MyInstance = this;
}
```

than you can use `MyInstance` instead of `this`.

Hope this helps.